# How to find friends that using the same app with facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm making an application that allow users register using facebook. I'm using the latest facebook sdk and parse for the backend. What I need is, How can I find friends of the current user that using the same app ?

Comment: that is very simple, what have you tried?

Comment: @ScottSelby actually I've never tried before, I found many tutorials but it's in objective c and using old facebook sdk

Comment: @ScottSelby do you know how to do that? or link that could lead me to what I want?

Comment: you know the users of your app  , and to get users friends you use graph api and go to /friends , then from there you find which users are in both lists

Comment: I already get the logic, but how can I do that? I found what I need but it uses earlier sdk from facebook and parse , here it is https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user

Answer (score 0):

This is Java Code. If you are not doing with java, do equivalent in you platform:

```
@Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            }

        protected void doFBLoginForProfile() {
        LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                getFriends();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, getReadPermissions());
    }

        private ArrayList<String> getReadPermissions() {
                ArrayList<String> fbPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
                fbPermissions.add("public_profile");
                fbPermissions.add("email");
                fbPermissions.add("user_location");
                fbPermissions.add("user_friends");
                return fbPermissions;
            }


        private void getFriends() {
                onShowFbProgress();
                if (hasGetFriendListPermission()) {
                    try {
                        GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONArray objects, GraphResponse response) {
                                Utils.displayLogs("FB", "FRIENDS LISTS " + objects);
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }

    public boolean hasGetFriendListPermission() {
            return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("user_friends");
        }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```